# Solutions of $(x^p - y^p)/(x - y) = z^p $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, cyclotomic-polynomials

I want to show that the diophantine equation

$ (x^p - y^p)/(x - y) = z^p $

where the prime $p > 3$, can just have trivial integer solutions $\{x, y, z\}$ like $\{1, -1, 1\}$

I used the theorem $IV$ from [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2007263.pdf) to resolve the case $(x - y) ≡ 0$ $mod(p)$.

Now, when $(x - y) ≢ 0$ $mod (p)$ we have

$ (x^p - y^p)/(x - y) = P[p] $

where $P[p]$ is the $arithmetic$ $primitive$ $factor$ of $  (x^p - y^p) $ defined in that article (p. $175$). With other considerations we can say that each one of those primitive prime factors is of the form $(2k_i p+1)$ where $k_i$ $∈ N$.

And so the question is: when $p > 3$, $P[p]$ can ever have this form?

$[(2k_i p+1)^i(2k_q p+1)^j...(2k_n p+1)^r]^p$

I guess I need Zsigmondy's theorem, but I'm stuck.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ep-y%5Ep%7D%7Bx-y%7D%3Dz%5Ep%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), there's the related [Question about (probably false) elementary proof of Fermat's Last Theorem](/q/2339328), [Wieferich's criterion for Fermat's Last Theorem](/q/2324411), [Question about proof correctness of a theorem related to FLT](/q/2526832), [Partial proof of first case of Fermat's Last Theorem](/q/2568354) and [Solution (y,z) coprime of $\frac{z^p-y^p}{z-y}=q^p$ for $5 \le p,q$ both prime?](/q/2552933).

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find a demonstration of what I'm looking for